# Android... positioning components accurately over background image

Tags: android, android-layout

I want my app to run on a wide variety of android devices in portrait only. I have a whole-screen background image that includes borders for other components. I want to place items like listviews/sponsor ads accurately within those borders... overlay them on top of the background in exactly the right place. Is using Framelayout the best/easiest way to do this? How do I make sure I get the listviews or sponsor ads in exactly the right place, and exactly the right size given that the background will be stretched to different dimensions for different devices? I've considered cutting up the background image instead but that seems like more work. What's the best approach? Thanks for any thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this scheme is never going to work consistently across all screen sizes.  If you want borders, you need to create 9-patch graphics out of those and assigne them as teh background to the UI item.

Comment: Thank you. My difficulty is that our iphone app I am trying to replicate has a background image that partially overlays (at top left corner) a thick top border (that includes header text) for a list view. I'm somewhat stumped as to the best way to do this on Android.